# google search engine problem

Tags: 14.04, chromium, google

When I search something on google, the tab freezes there are no result. This doesn't happen all the time, usually 80% of the time. I can open a new tab and surf the web on that. This has never happened to me. It just started thursday night. I am using firefox. Someone suggested to use another web browser so I used chrome/Chromium but the same thing happened on google and this time, the whole thing froze not just the tab. Any other website I use like youtube,Quora works fine. I cleaned up all the history, cookies, temporary internet files, everything.

OS used :Ubuntu 14.04

Something like this

[image]

please help

Comment: This isn't necessarily something related to Ubuntu. Its Google stuff. http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: How about Google from other location, like  Canada or UK ? Do those sites work ?

Comment: looks like you need to clear you dns cache on your DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the instant search option on Google. There are a few possibilities why it isn't working, and they are covered on Google support here: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/186645?hl=en